# Constructing a sample by correlation

Tags: correlation

Suppose we have two samples with known correlation (should be relatively high). Say both samples have $n$ data points. What if now we still know the correlation factor but one sample only consistent of the first 5 data point.

Could one still construct the remaining data points solely using the correlation with the other sample?

My idea would be to look at the relative differences in the known sample and compensate by the correlation. Could this work? Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula for the correlation coefficient to generate an equation:$$\overline r=\large{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\overline{x}\right)\left(y_{i}-\overline{y}\right)}{‌​\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\overline{x}\right)^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_{i} - \overline{y} \right)^2}}}$$

Suppose you have three data points :

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline x&1&3&5  \\ \hline y&2 & &  \\ \hline\end{array}$

And the desired value for $\overline r$ is $0.9$.

The equation becomes

$0.9=\large{\frac{(-2)\cdot \left( 2-\frac{1}{3}\cdot (2+y_2+y_3)\right)+(0)\cdot \left( y_2-\frac{1}{3}\cdot (2+y_2+y_3)\right)+(2)\cdot \left( y_3-\frac{1}{3}\cdot (2+y_2+y_3)\right)}{\left( (-2)^2+0^2+2^2\right) \cdot \left( \left(2-\frac{1}{3}\cdot (2+y_2+y_3) \right)^2+\left(y_2-\frac{1}{3}\cdot (2+y_2+y_3) \right)^2+\left( y_3-\frac{1}{3}\cdot (2+y_2+y_3)\right)^2\right)}}$

This equation has $\texttt{more than one}$ solution and it is not easy to solve. But in general it is possible.

Comment: What if one would add one data point at a time and keep the correlation constant? Would it make it any easier computationally?

Comment: You mean $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline x&1&3&5  \\ \hline y&2 & 7 &  \color{red}? \\ \hline\end{array}$ and and $\overline r$ is arbitrary ? In this case the solution is unique. It should be easier because you have less variables, in this case one.

Comment: If you add the data point $(x_3/y_3)$ than you have infinite solutions again. In this case you can simplify your calculation by setting $x_3=5$ as in the previous comment, but $x_3$ can also be $0$.

Comment: In the case the solution is unique, is it possible to rewrite the expression explicitly? I'm trying that but it doesn't seem easy.

Comment: I becomes a quadratic equation. The numerator is linear. But the denominator is quadratic. After you have set $y_2=7$ you have to multiply  both sides be the denominator. Then you have to multiply out all the brackets and collect the $y_3^2, y_3^1$ and $y_3^0$ (constants) terms. Then you have a quadratic equation which can be solved by the well known formula. Therefore you have two solutions not one. Sure it is a lot of work.

Comment: It seems so indeed. Could there be alternatives to estimate a line with a starting point from an observed highly correlated line?